# How to save image to external directory - iOS?

Tags: dart, flutter

how to get access to the external directory i.e to camera roll and save an image in the external directory on iOS using flutter? so that the captured image will be viewed from the photo app.

Comment: What do you mean by external directory?
Have had a look at the path_provider package?
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider

Comment: say, for example, if I downloaded the image or pdf it should be accessed outside the app like opening pdf by pdf viewer. Path provider gives getApplicationDocumentsDirectory which is NSDocumentsDirectory, it will be accessed by the own app. The app which I am working handles camera to capture images and downloads pdf from the given url.

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing like that in Flutter so far. You may need to implement it in the native side yourself and access it from your Dart code using Platform Channels

Answer (score 1):

So iOS doesn't actually have a notion of an external directory AFAIK.

In terms of saving photos or videos to camera roll or albums, there is a plugin, [flutter_photokit](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_photokit) that will allow you to do just that. You would need to save the photo/video to either the application documents directory or temporary directory (using [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider)) and then you can do the following:

```
FlutterPhotokit.saveToCameraRoll(filePath: '/path/to/photo.jpg');
// OR
FlutterPhotokit.saveToAlbum(filePath: '/path/to/video.mp4', albumName: 'MyAlbum');
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of this plugin

Comment: Thank for the great work, i saw your code which handles image and video to save, any idea to download and view pdf file. any help/suggestion would be helpful for me.

Comment: You want the PDFs to be accessible from other apps or just within your app?

Comment: I think the [share](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share) plugin may do what you want. You can use it to share things with other apps (like opening a PDF with another app). I don't think it supports file sharing atm, but I've seen some pull requests to add that functionality